# Evaluating $\int \frac{x^2}{1+e^{-x}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider $$\int \frac{x^2}{1+e^{-x}}dx$$

I've tried every method and trick that I'm familiar with, except by parts, but I can't seem to be able to acquire an elementary integral. Does there exist one? If so, what would it be?

Comment: Are there limits for the integral?

Comment: No limits here, just a plain indefinite integral.

Comment: Please ensure that your question is fully understandable without the title. The title's purpose is to attract people to your question (and to make it easily searchable). Once it has done that, its job is done. The question should be self-contained.

Comment: Are you sure this can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions? Also, make sure you've read the question correctly. It seems, according to Wolfram, that this integral is solved via Polylogarithms.

Comment: I didn't claim that it can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. I saw that Wolfram used polylogarithms, but I'm not sure if that guarantees that the integral is non-elementary immediately. I had suspected there was a non-elementary integral but I wasn't completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mathematica, this integral cannot be expressed as a combination of elementary functions. The provided answer is:

$$ I = x^2 \ln{(1+e^{-x})} + 2x \, \mathrm{Li}_2 (e^{-x}) -2 \, \mathrm{Li}_3(-e^x), $$ where $\mathrm{Li}_n(x)$ is the [polylogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html).

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

---

I have just noticed that you find out the answer (at least partially) by yourself. Please let me know if my answer should be removed.