# Calculate $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{t^{2}}{1+\exp(t)}dt$, whose indefinite integral is of non-elementary function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Calculate $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{t^{2}}{1+\exp(t)}dt$$

I know an approach is using the change of variables $t=-u$, so we have the value for the integral $\frac{1}{3}$. How can I calculate that integral using other approach?

I thought about this  problem when observing this indefinite integral [indefinite integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1268227/798113).

Comment: As the questioned you have mentioned shows in the answers, this integral involves some horrible functions in the indefinite form, and whilst substituting the bounds in would give you the correct answer it is much easier to use the trick you have mentioned in cases like this

Comment: Do you know other approach for this prolem? I'm interesting in find other approach.

Comment: This is definite integral

Comment: @Anixx Yes, I know. But, the title is precise. In my post, I'm looking for different approach for to calculate this definite integral. I think we can find differents approach for to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Note that
$\ds{\left.{1 \over \expo{t} + 1}\,
\right\vert_{\,t\ \not=\ 0} = \Theta\pars{-t} +
{\on{sgn}\pars{t} \over \expo{\verts{t}} + 1}}$ and equal to $\ds{1 \over 2}$ when $\ds{t = 0}$. $\ds{\Theta}$ is the *Heaviside Theta* or/and *Step Function*.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{-1}^{1}{t^{2} \over 1 + \expo{t}}\,\dd t} =
\int_{-1}^{0}t^{2}\,\dd t = \bbx{1 \over 3} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Nice solution. Indeed if $f(t)$ is even function and integrable in $[0,x]$, so we have $\displaystyle \int_{-x}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{1+e^{t}}dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$. In our case we have $f(t)=t^{2}$.

Comment: @АлександрПальма I added some comment at the top of my answer. Please, read it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Fantastic, do you think other approach for thr problem?

Comment: @АлександрПальма This is a usual identity in Satistical Physics. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$\frac1{1+e^t} = \frac12 -\frac12\tanh\frac t2$$
and the odd function $\tanh\frac t2$ does not survives the integration over $(-1,1)$. Thus, the integral reduces to
$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{t^{2}}2 dt=\frac13$.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank so much.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{t^{2}}{1+e^t}dt=\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{t^{2}}{1+e^t}dt+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2}}{1+e^t}dt$$$$. $$
Under $t\to-t$,
$$\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{t^{2}}{1+e^t}dt=\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{1+e^{-t}}dt=\int_0^1\frac{t^2e^t}{1+et^t}dt$$
and hence
$$ I=\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{t^{2}}{1+e^t}dt+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2}}{1+e^t}dt=\int_0^1\frac{t^2+t^2e^t}{1+t^2}dt=\int_0^1t^2dt=\frac13. $$

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe do you know other approach for this problem? I think we can find 10 different approach for to solve this problem :)

Comment: @xpaul You shall consider editing your answer in the second formula (both the denominators after the first $=$ sign are not correct) and in the second formula (the denominator after the second $=$ sign is not correct). Nice answer!

Comment: @Nicolas, you are right. Thanks

Comment: @АлександрПальма, you can try $u=1+e^t$. I think it works too.